# All different size groups to create m groups from n samples

Tags: mathematical-statistics, combinatorics

Suppose we have $n$ samples that we want to divide in $m$ groups. How can we get the total number of groups and their sizes (if possible)?
Examples:
For $n = 6$ and $m = 3$ we would have $3$ groups as follows:
·|·|····
··|·|···
··|··|··
For $n = 4$ and $m = 2$ we would have $2$ groups as follows:
·|···
··|··

All other groupings would be redundant in both cases.

Comment: you appear to be asking about counting partitions into exactly $k$ parts --  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts - is that correct?

Comment: @Glen_b yessir, thanks for the link.